# In how many ways can N balls be distributed in M slots?

Tags: combinatorics

If I have M slots, and N balls, and M > N, in how many ways can balls be distributed in slots? Each slot can have at most 1 ball.

UPDATE:

Ok, so the original form of the task was like this: There are 2 processes (think computer processes), each performing 4 operations. Both run simultanousely. Let's say there is process with operations 1-2-3-4, and another one with a-b-c-d. Because processes run simultanousely, operations can be performed in different order. It can be 1-2-3-4-a-b-c-d, or 1-a-2-b-3-c-4-d or 1-2-3-a-b-4-c-d etc. The question is how many such combinations do we have. It is important that in the process, operations must keep order. I.e. we can't have e.g. 2-1 or d-b anywhere.

I figured out there are always 8 operations (not a huge discovery here ;) ). Let's say this are slots. Now I have to place 4 operations in 8 slots - another 4 will just fill remaining ones. Then I figured out I don't need to label the 4 operations, because their order will be always the same. So the whole task boils down to putting 4 balls in 8 slots.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! Please add some context to your question: what have you tried and where do you get stuck. This will help other users provide an appropriate answer.

Comment: This is the stars and bars problem. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just selecting N slots out of M.....

Comment: Selecting... You are right! Thanks @g1c :)

Comment: you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

M!/((M-N)!*N!)

Think of it this way. The first ball can go to any of M slots. **And** second ball can go to any of M-1 slots,  ..., **and** i-th ball can go to (M+1-i) slots .. and n-th ball can go to (M+1-N). Multiply "anded" operations (add "ored" operations). You get M*(M-1)*...*(M-N+1) = M!/(M-N)! This result counts permutations separately.

Ball1 ->(1), Ball2 -> (2) and
Ball1 ->(2), Ball2 -> (1)

are counted as separate entries. Divade by number of permutations (N!)

result is M!/((M-N)!*N!)